# Detect if there are items left to scroll in a flutter Listview

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have listview in a gridview in a flutter calendar app. I am trying to detect if a particular list view has half-visible or invisible items which need to be scrolled to be seen. If not, the user might not see that a day has an appointment/task unless they change resolution/view.

I'd like to add a little arrow, or overlay, just to warn the user there are extra items. Making the listview scrollable doesn't work well for me because then the gridview loses scrollability, unless I make the ListViews shrinkwrap, which causes its own problems.

Any help appreciated...

[image: Here is a pic]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an Text to tell the user there is more contact and if the list is on end you remove that text
by using this inview_notifier_list package
and check if onListEndReached